# Cryptic clue puzzle (easy)

Tags: cryptic-clues, cryptic-crosswords

Here are a few easy cryptic clues I created! (Lengths are hidden in case you want an extra challenge)

1) *Depressed in Widow nightmare.*

> (4)

2) *Star lit up rebel city.*

> (9)

3) *Former wine "contains exhaust"*

> (7)

4) *Wicked "back to walk the earth!"*

> (4)

5) *Moral within "Marathon" establishment?*

> (6)

6) *American state upsets old fair*

> (7)

7) *Tree droppings, "go away!"*

> (6)

8) *Small discount mound*

> (4)

This is my first time creating cryptics, so please suggest any improvements I can make!

Here is a clue for #8, in case I made it too difficult.

> Find a synonym of [discount](http://www.thesaurus.com/browse/at%20a%20discount), and remove a letter to find a word meaning [mound](http://www.thesaurus.com/browse/mound?s=t).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Hopefully that's all of them:

1) *Depressed in Widow nightmare.*

> DOWN (4) - Depressed in Wi**DOW N**ightmare [[found by Duncan]]

2) *Star lit up rebel city.*

> CELEBRITY (9) - anagram of 'rebel city'

3) *Former wine "contains exhaust"*

> RETIRED (7) - TIRE means to exhaust, surrounded by RED as in red wine [[found by Gareth McCaughan]]

4) *Wicked "back to walk the earth!"*

> LIVE (4) - when reversed becomes EVIL and only living things walk the earth (NOTE: This clue works with either LIVE or EVIL as the answer.)

5) *Moral within "Marathon" establishment?*

> HONEST (6) - within "Marat**HON EST**ablishment

6) *American state upsets old fair*

> FLORIDA (7) - anagram of 'Old Fair'

7) *Tree droppings, "go away!"*

> LEAVES (6) - fall from trees and LEAVE is to go away
>  (**Suggestion**: This clue ought to be tweaked so that the two parts are either both plural or singular, possibly something like: *Trees do this: go away!* with an answer of LEAVE (5)

8) *Small discount mound* (after looking at the clue)

> HEAP (4) - Discount means CHEAP, 'small' suggests shortening the word to give HEAP which is a mound.
>  [[Note: Just as I'm about to press save edits, I've noticed that Jonathan has this answer as well]]

Comment: Well done so far! Correct: (1, 2, 5, 6, 7) ... 4 is very close to being correct

Comment: 4 works about equally well the other way around (i.e., "wicked" is the def and "back to walk the earth" is the wordplay).

Comment: All correct except for 8

Comment: Correct, well done!

Answer (score 4):

Here's what I have so far. Reasonings separate for those who want to work it out on their own.

1) Depressed in Widow nightmare.

> Down.

Reasoning:

> Hidden in wi**dow n**ightmare.

2) Star lit up rebel city.

> Celebrity (from Gordon K)

Reasoning:

> Anagram of rebel city

3) Former wine "contains exhaust"

> Retired

Reasoning:

> Retired = former. And "red" (a wine) contains "tire" (to exhaust)

4) Wicked "back to walk the earth!"

> Live

Reasoning:

> Wicked = evil, backwards = live. "To walk the earth" is to "live".

5) Moral within "Marathon" establishment?

> Honest.

Reasoning:

> "within" Marat**hon est**ablishment

6) American state upsets old fair

> Florida.

Reasoning:

> Anagram of "old fair"

7) Tree droppings, "go away!"

> Leaves? Not sure about this one.

Reasoning:

> Trees drop leaves. To leave is to go away.

8) Small discount mound

> Scut?

Reasoning:

> Small = s, a discount is a "cut" in the price. "Scut" (I had to look it up), is the short tail of a rabbit or deer - often just a little mound. This one's a stretch, but if it's right it's a good vocabulary word!

Comment: @Duncan Your answer for number 8 is as close as I could find too.

Comment: Yeah - I'm still thinking on it, as I don't love that answer for "mound", but I'm not coming up with anything.

Comment: #8 is incorrect, all others are correct

Answer (score 3):

Possible answer to number eight 
8) Small discount mound

> Heap

Comment: Correct well done!

Answer (score 2):

Filling in one no one else has yet:

3. Former wine "contains exhaust" (7)

> RE(TIRE)D

I'm still stuck on #8; I suspect it may involve a word meaning "discount" (or "small discount") that I either don't know or am suffering a blind spot about.

Answer (score 1):

Filling in #8 (hopefully):

8) *Small discount mound*

> DEAL - A discount is known as a deal and another word for a mound is a deal (I think)

Comment: I can't find any source confirming that word is used to mean mound Edit: I just found that word used in conjunction with great i.e. great ___ so maybe that

Comment: Good try but incorrect